# How to import the json file in python

Tags: python, json, excel

I am trying to import a json file to python and then export is to an excel file using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('pub_settings.json')
df.to_excel('pub_settings.xlsx')
```

but i am getting the following error:
[image: error screenshot]

can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the inside of the json file is formatted correctly? Could you show us the beginning of the data in it? The more you copy from it the better.

Comment: Make sure the JSON matches the [supported formats](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-json).

Answer (score 0):

First import json file as a dictionary using following code:-

```
import json
with open("") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then you can use following link to convert it to xlsx:-

https://pypi.org/project/tablib/0.9.3/